# MySQL very slow query using left joins

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, left-join

I have this query that runs on a fairly large set of data.
It is *extremely* slow...

I need to optimize this query, and not sure where to start (aside from indexes).

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT d.distributor_id, 
d.first_name,
d.last_name,
d.sponsor_id,
COUNT(f.business_level) AS total_enrollments,
SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(f.business_level) = 'EXECUTIVE' THEN 1 else 0 end)
    AS executive_enrollments,
SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(f.business_level) = 'PERSONAL' THEN 1 else 0 end)
    AS personal_enrollments,
SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(f.business_level) = 'PREFERRED CUSTOMER' THEN 1 else 0 end)
    AS preferred_customer_enrollments,
IFNULL(cf.commission_paid, 0) AS commission_paid,
IFNULL(cf.retention_earned, 0) AS retention_earned,
COUNT(df.order_type) AS total_autoships,
IFNULL(a.consecutive_streak, 0) AS autoship_streak,
IFNULL(a.enrollment_date, "Not Enrolled") AS autoship_enrollment,
d.highest_rank
    FROM warehouse.distributor d
        LEFT JOIN warehouse.enrollment_detail_fact f ON d.distributor_id = f.distributor_id
        LEFT JOIN warehouse.country c ON d.country = c.name
             AND c.country_id = 185
        LEFT JOIN warehouse.autoship a ON d.distributor_id = a.distributor_id
        LEFT JOIN warehouse.order_detail_fact df ON d.distributor_id = df.distributor_id
            AND UPPER(order_type) = 'AUTOSHIP'
            AND date_id IN(SELECT date_id FROM warehouse.date
                WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2012-10-10'
                AND '2012-10-11' ORDER BY date DESC)
        LEFT JOIN warehouse.commission_detail_fact cf ON d.distributor_id = df.distributor_id
        LEFT JOIN db.commission_level_type_details cl ON d.highest_rank = cl.name
WHERE d.active = 1               
    AND cl.commission_level_type_detail_id IN (23)
GROUP BY distributor_id
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Comment: I understand that the data needs to be indexed correctly, I'm wondering if there is an alternate way to write this query that would allow it to be better optimized.

Comment: @Crobzilla That is basically impossible to answer without understanding the schema of all the tables involved and what they represent in real-world terms as it related to the information you are trying to derive from the tables.

Comment: Great question! Thanks for sharing. I've updated my thoughts in my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would try moving this WHERE clause into the JOIN clause:

```
AND cl.commission_level_type_detail_id IN (23)
```

Add it to this JOIN clause:

```
LEFT JOIN db.commission_level_type_details cl ON d.highest_rank = cl.name
```

For this JOIN clause:

```
LEFT JOIN warehouse.order_detail_fact df ON d.distributor_id = df.distributor_id
            AND UPPER(order_type) = 'AUTOSHIP'
            AND date_id IN(SELECT date_id FROM warehouse.date
                WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2012-10-10'
                AND '2012-10-11' ORDER BY date DESC)
```

I would normalize this data structure ***AND UPPER(order_type) = 'AUTOSHIP')*** to an "order_type" table and use the indexed integer ID instead. Much more efficient.

I would also de-normalize the date_id (not sure why one would normalize a record's date, perhaps I'm missing some of the business requirements). Just have the date in the same table, index it and let MySQL do what it does best. That embedded SELECT in your WHERE clause is not indexed and as such MySQL cannot handle that data optimally.

As a matter of fact, I would normalize everything in the JOIN and WHERE clauses that is NOT an INTEGER. Turn them into Integer IDs. This will drastically reduce performance costs. As a rule of thumb I never ask the DB server to perform a seek on an alpha-numeric index.

I'll edit and post more as I think of them.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: My guess based on the names of the tables is that this is a star schema database used for data warehousing (data warehousing folks love to name tables as "fact tables"). One common thing you will see in such data warehouses is handling of dates with a common date dimension table.  This allows for easier date aggregation for various date query criteria in reporting (day of week, week, month, quarter, year, etc.). So this probably would not be a candidate for de-normalization (doing so would require those sorts of fields in all tables where you need to aggregate on such dates).

Comment: Ahh yes... I had a feeling it was some obscure data handling requirement specific to the intended data application. I guess one way we could go about it would be to add de-normalized date fields for reporting purposes. Of ourse they'd have to be updated but better looking up those dates once than every time you need to report on it. Or maybe just move the data over to a Reporting Database or Tables and de-normalize upon replication. Just thinking out loud. :-) Thanks for the insights Mike.

Comment: I think the thing is, this IS the reporting database.  Think about some typical MySQL table with lots of records with timestamps.  Now say you copied that table over to a reporting database as is and wanted to do some analytics to find out out the average number of order by day of the week over a whole year.  This would be a painful query using datetime fields as there is now way to query by all Mondays, Tuesdays, etc. while also using an index. So what you do is build date and time tables like described here http://tech.akom.net/archives/36-Creating-A-Basic-Date-Dimension-Table-in-MySQL.html

Comment: And you then replace the datetime entries on the data table with the corresponding id entries in the date and/or time tables.  This allows you to do lookups like `SELECT AVG(dft.datafield), dt.day_of_week FROM data_fact_table AS dft JOIN date_table AS dt on dft.date_id = dt.date_id GROUP BY dt.day_of_week`.  This is a nice clean lookup that uses indexes on date_id in both tables. Also the date table can be joined to any other table in the warehouse in a similar manner meaning there is only one place where you need to keep all your date data.

Comment: Still brings me back to de-normalization. If this is in fact the reporting table, and "day of week" was a reporting criteria, then I would simply add a day_of_week int field and update it based on the desired date, index it and be done. Especially if these are archived records with little or not need to update those dates. But yes, I get your explanation of the use-case. Thanks Mike.

Comment: Ahh but the purpose of the date table is to where you only have to have a date_id in the fact table.  The properties of the dateid (what day of week, month, quarter, etc. it is is a field property only in the data table, the fact table doesn't need to know anything other than what it's date and/or time id's are.  You could then theoretically add additional properties on the date table (months by zodiac for example) without having to modify the fact table at all. There is no reason to add fields for every date property you might want to track to every single fact table.

Comment: In fact, say you had a fact table with 100 million rows, it would be EXTREMELY expensive to have to index dozens of date fields on that table in order to give you flexible date querying.  It is much better to have a single indexed date field on the fact table.  You then have indexes on all the date properties in the date table which may only consist of several thousand rows depending on what the date range of your date table is.

Comment: One of the key concepts in the star or snowflake data warehosuing approach is to heavily normalize your very large fact tables and have smaller dimension tables for things like date, time, geographical divisions, products (if you don't have millions of products), salespersons, warehoouse identifiers, etc. that may be common amongst many fact tables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you say "aside from indexes".  That would be the first place I would start looking for optimizations.  Every single field you are using for the joins, the WHERE clause filtering, the grouping, and the sorting should have an index on it. You should also, explicitly define the tables associated with the fields used in GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

You should eliminate things like this

```
UPPER(order_type) = 'AUTOSHIP'
```

Where you are using these values for joins, filtering, grouping, as this will prevent the index on the field from being used.  You also lose some performance when using these UPPER function calls in the SELECT statement (those these are not a expensive performance-wise  as when they cause you to not use an index). If your data is properly sanitized you shouldn't need these.

You should probably also look to eliminate that sub select by just inner joining on the date table and adding the date range filter to your main WHERE clause.  Similarly, you have other cases where you are using filters that should probably go into your WHERE clause as join fields.  If for nothing other than for readability of the query, I would just join the tables on the appropriate keys and place all the filtering logic in WHERE clause.

It looks like you are dealing with a star-schema data warehouse, so even after optimizing indexes and removing the subselect, if you have large amounts of data, you still may have a slow query.

Comment: Yes, I am already creating the needed indexes which is why I listed 'aside from indexes'.  Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

#### Useless ORDER BY clause

Clearly, this `ORDER BY` clause is completely useless:

```
AND date_id IN(SELECT date_id FROM warehouse.date
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2012-10-10'
    AND '2012-10-11' ORDER BY date DESC)
                  -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ remove this!
```

I'm not sure if MySQL is smart enough to optimise this away, so that might be some improvement...

#### JOIN predicates based on VARCHAR, rather than INT

These join predicates:

```
LEFT JOIN warehouse.country c ON d.country = c.name
```

... they would perform much better if they were:

```
LEFT JOIN warehouse.country c ON d.country_id = c.id
```

#### And the most important problem: Misusing LEFT JOIN leads to cartesian products

You most certainly have a cartesian product between your relations `f` and `df`, as you erroneously `LEFT JOIN` them both to `d`. This means, your query isn't just slow, but probably also *wrong*. For example:

```
COUNT(df.order_type) AS total_autoships,
-- [...]
LEFT JOIN warehouse.order_detail_fact df ON d.distributor_id = df.distributor_id
        AND UPPER(order_type) = 'AUTOSHIP'
        AND date_id IN(SELECT date_id FROM warehouse.date
            WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2012-10-10'
            AND '2012-10-11' ORDER BY date DESC)
```

... is probably wrong. By itself, the `COUNT` may still be correct, but since you join other 1:N relationships, that `COUNT` probably explodes to unrealistic values. Better write:

```
COUNT((SELECT df.order_type
       FROM   warehouse.order_detail_fact df
       WHERE  d.distributor_id = df.distributor_id
       AND    ...)) 
    AS total_autoships
```

Or `JOIN` the aggregated values directly:

```
df.total_autoships AS total_autoships,
-- [...]
JOIN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(order_type) AS total_autoships 
    FROM   warehouse.order_detail_fact 
    WHERE  d.distributor_id = distributor_id
    AND    ...
) df
```